# Read Kafka previous messages (not live feed)

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to read previous messages in `kafka`?
Not from live feed?
I have this command:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic topicName --consumer group
```

It works like a charm for live feed.
But is there a way to read what was sent in previously?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "**--from-beginning**"

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topicName --consumer group --from-beginning
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it is also just reads the live feed. I read that I have to do something with the offset, but I am not on that level in kafka. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: "--from-beginning" will read all the messages that are in the topic, if you want to read  messages from specific partition and starting at a specific offset, you can use --offset : "kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic topicName --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partition 2 --offset 2235439 "
And if you want to read one message you can add "--max-messages 1"

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Great ! You're welcome